# How to remove duplicate and unnecessary part in a url using htaccess and regex?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I want to permanently redirect some URLs that have been removed and robots insist on following it. I have the default WordPress configuration for `.htaccess`.

```
www.example.com/customers/em/customers/any-url
```

to

```
www.example.com/customers/any-url
```

and

```
www.example.com/any-url/map/?str=Av+street+Fight,+19&cit=Alabama&sta=San+Paolo
```

to

```
www.example.com/customers/any-url
```

My htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm the _variable_ and _literal_ parts of the URLs you want to redirect. `any-url` is presumably variable, but is this a single path segment or an entirely variable URL-path? Is the query string in your second example an exact literal string that needs to be matched?

Comment: any-url are thousands of urls that were incorrectly indexed by robots, then due to the amount it is impossible to manually redirect each one. I need to put this in htaccess for it to be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `any-url` is literally any URL-path like `foo` or `foo/bar/baz/something`, but not *nothing*.

Try the following:

```
# Redirect "/customers/em/customers/any-url" to "/customers/any-url"
RewriteRule ^(customers)/em/customers/(.+) /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains "customers" (saves repetition) from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. And the `$2` backreference contains the `any-url` part. Any query string that might be present on the request is passed through unchanged.

With regards to the URL `/any-url/map/?str=Av+street+Fight,+19&cit=Alabama&sta=San+Paolo`, you've not actually stated whether the query string is literal or variable - I'm assuming the query string is literal and must be matched exactly as written. In this case you would need to do something like the following:

```
# Redirect "/any-url/map/?str=<value>" to "/customers/any-url"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =str=Av+street+Fight,+19&cit=Alabama&sta=San+Paolo
RewriteRule ^(.+)/map/$ /customers/$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `=` prefix-operator on the *CondPattern* (2nd argument of the `RewriteCond` directive) makes it a lexicographical string comparison (not a regex), so the string is matched literally.

The `QSD` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive is necessary to discard the query string from the initial request.

If, however, the `str` URL parameter should accept any non-empty *value* then change the above *CondPattern* to read: `^str=.`.

These redirects need to go at the *top* of `.htaccess` file, *before* your existing directives (the WordPress front-controller), otherwise they are likely to not get processed.

You should also test first with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have fully tested that they work as intended. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

Ensure the browser cache is cleared before testing.

Reference:

- [Apache mod_rewrite - RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) / [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)